# MongoDb Field Encryption

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, encryption

I am trying to set up a system where I can have a collection of users with encrypted fields and do a search on those fields.

I have tried looking on MongoDB documentation but there is no clear route

I want to have something like this

```
{
    fname : John,
    lname : Smith,
    ssn : "555-55-5555"
}
```

look like this

```
{
    fname : John,
    lname : Smith,
    ssn : "fweiubv3b443hbv4f48h"
}
```

then be able to do a search like

```sh
db.users.find({ssn : "555-55-5555"})
```

The goal is to have a schema run and create the collection

```js
db.createCollection("user", {
    "validator": {
       "$jsonSchema": {
           ....
});
```

Comment: My first thought is you would be in control of the encryption.  You'd encrypt it before storing it in the collection.  Then if you wanted to find something, you'd encrypt the value, and search with the encrypted value.

Comment: @Taplar A somewhat good idea, but does limit the security of the encryption significantly - to do this, you could only ever use ECB mode, which has many known security issues.

Answer (score 1):

A common strategy to solve this problem requires two fields on the model.  One is a hash, the other is the result of encryption.

Taking your SSN example:

#### Storing

- Take the plaintext SSN and HMAC it using `key1`.
- Take the plaintext SSN and encrypt it using a AAED mode like `GCM` with `key2`.
- Store the hash and encryption result in the database document or whatever.  Names like `ssn_hash` and `ssn_enc` might be appropriate.

#### Looking Up

- Take the SSN you are searching for and HMAC it using `key1`.
- Perform a lookup on `ssn_hash` for the result above.

#### Getting Plaintext

- Lookup the database document however.
- Decrypt `ssn_enc` with `key2`.